# Effective way to extract this line of text

Tags: powershell

I have started with my journey of learning power shell and with the generous feedback of others i have finally almost completed my first useful script and customized it to my liking , i just need a bit of help getting over this last hurdle, I have tried a few methods and just cant seem to get the result I want

**The Aim**

To take a text file which includes the following mess

```
Set WN = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
US=WN.USERNAME
D="q,\\abc-filesvr-03\shared$,g,\\abc-ngfs-01\pingate$,s,\\abc-ngfs-01\mdis-com$,i,\\abc-civica-01\icondata$"
A=SPLIT(D,",")
DO UNTIL B>UBOUND(A) 
MAPDRIVE A(B),A(B+1)
B=B+2
LOOP


Sub MapDrive(DriveLetter, UNCPath)
    on error resume next
    WN.RemoveNetworkDrive DriveLetter&":",1,1
    on error resume next
    WN.MapNetworkDrive DriveLetter&":",UNCPath
    if err<>0 then 
    'ws.EXEC "msg.exe %username% Message from LOGON script - Error connecting drive " & DriveLetter & " to " & UNCPath & " - user is    " & US& " - Further message is - " & err.description
    'ER " Message from LOGON script - Error connecting drive " & DriveLetter & " to " & UNCPath & " - user is " & US& " - Further message is - " & err.description
    end if
End Sub


sub er(m)
    m = m & wn.computername
    PF = "\\abc-ngfs-01\logons$\ERRORS"
    PT = PF & "\" & US
    SET OBJFSO = CREATEOBJECT("scripting.filesystemobject")
    if OBJFSO.FOLDEREXISTS(PF) THEN
        F = 1
        DO UNTIL NOT OBJFSO.FILEEXISTS(PT & F)
            F = F + 1
        LOOP
        OBJFSO.CREATETEXTFILE(PT & F)
        set fl = OBJFSO.opentextfile(PT & F,8)
        fl.write(DATE & "[]" & TIME & "[]" & us & "[]" & m & "[][][]")
        fl.close
        set fl = nothing
    END IF
end sub
```

Extract the parts which include the drives(The below), and store this in a variable for later use

```
D="q,\\abc-filesvr-03\shared$,g,\\abc-ngfs-01\pingate$,s,\\abc-ngfs-01\mdis-com$,i,\\abc-civica-01\icondata$"
```

Depending on the text file which is used the drives names will change so I cant pre-specify this

I have experimented with trying to use file filters,which have a list of words or symbols to exclude - didn't seem to get anywhere with this

For example

```
    $inputfile = "C:\users\admin\desktop\inputfile.txt"
    $outputfile = "C:\users\admin\desktop\outputfile.txt"
    $filterFile = "C:\users\admin\desktop\filterFile.txt"
    $filters = Get-Content $filterFile
    Get-Content $inputFile | Select-String -pattern $filters -notMatch | Out-File $outputFile
```

Just wondering if anyone can think of an effective method to use as i feel like i'm over complicating this massively?

Comment: Can you give an example of where the line is split up in two? The data looks like VBScript, so I assume the line continuation mark `& _` will be present then?

Comment: After taking a look it appears only to be admin accounts that spill over so it shouldn't matter for what this script is going to be used for. Apologies i should of had a better look into this, and yes that's correct it's a vbs script which has been changed to a .txt document , having a look into a couple of them &_ doesn't seem to be present

Comment: Does this mean you have it solved? We don't know what is in your pattern (and if you want to match something, why use `-notmatch`)?

Comment: I dont have it solved no, I have edited my post and removed that section regarding it spilling over into two lines (apologies). -notmatch was just an attempt I made at trying to get the correct result. Once I have some free time I'll edit the post to include more useful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single inputfile, you can use:

```
$inputfile = "C:\users\admin\desktop\inputfile.txt"
$drives = (Select-String -Path $inputfile -Pattern '(D=.+)').Line
```

Result

> ```
> $drives --> D="q,\\abc-filesvr-03\shared$,g,\\abc-ngfs-01\pingate$,s,\\abc-ngfs-01\mdis-com$,i,\\abc-civica-01\icondata$"
> ```

If you want that split into objects with properties Driveletter and Path:

```
$items = $drives -replace '^D=|"' -split ',' 
for ($i = 0; $i -le $items.Count - 1; $i +=2) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{DriveLetter = $items[$i]; Path = $items[$i + 1]}
}
```

Result

> ```
> DriveLetter Path                     
> ----------- ----                     
> q           \\abc-filesvr-03\shared$ 
> g           \\abc-ngfs-01\pingate$   
> s           \\abc-ngfs-01\mdis-com$  
> i           \\abc-civica-01\icondata$
> ```

When using this on a series of files in a folder:

```
$inputPath = 'C:\users\admin\desktop'
Get-ChildItem -Path $inputPath -Filter '*.txt' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $drives = ($_ | Select-String -Pattern '(D=.+)').Line
    if ($drives) {
        $items = $drives.Trim() -replace '^D=|"' -split ',' 
        for ($i = 0; $i -le $items.Count - 1; $i +=2) {
            # add the file where this was found in the output
            [PsCustomObject]@{DriveLetter = $items[$i]; Path = $items[$i + 1]; SourceFile = $_.FullName}
        } 
    }
}
```

Result:

> ```
> DriveLetter Path                      SourceFile                   
> ----------- ----                      ----------                
> q           \\abc-filesvr-03\shared$  C:\users\admin\desktop\inputfile.txt  
> g           \\abc-ngfs-01\pingate$    C:\users\admin\desktop\inputfile.txt  
> s           \\abc-ngfs-01\mdis-com$   C:\users\admin\desktop\inputfile.txt  
> i           \\abc-civica-01\icondata$ C:\users\admin\desktop\inputfile.txt 
> q           \\abc-filesvr-03\shared$  C:\users\admin\desktop\anotherfile.txt
> g           \\abc-ngfs-01\pingate$    C:\users\admin\desktop\anotherfile.txt
> s           \\abc-ngfs-01\mdis-com$   C:\users\admin\desktop\anotherfile.txt  
> i           \\abc-civica-01\icondata$ C:\users\admin\desktop\anotherfile.txt
> ```

If you want to save this to a new output csv file, just add

```
| Export-Csv -Path 'C:\users\admin\desktop\outputfile.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

after the final curly bracket `}`

Hope that helps

Comment: Once again thanks so much, much more than I ever expected, tested on a couple of different examples and it works perfectly. Think i'll spend some time learning the commands above so i can use this independently whenever I need to - thanks!

Comment: @sheady Glad to have helped and thanks for the nice feedback!